# Google Cloud Storage, how to get original filename for the file downloaded using signed url. Content-Disposition header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, content-disposition, pre-signed-url

For example, we have a bucket `"example_bucket"`, and in this bucket we have uploaded file with filename `"first_file.jpeg"`. Now, I want to create signed url for this file, using cli tool I run next command `gsutil -m signurl -r <region> <path_to_the_service_account> gs://example_bucket/first_file.jpeg` which will return signed url, using this url I want to download this file, but response doesn't contains any filename information(I wanna get original `"first_file.jpeg"` filename).

Comment: Can you try to clarify your question? You are not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: For example, we have a bucket `"example_bucket"`, and in this bucket we have uploaded file with filename `"first_file.jpeg"`. Now, I want to create signed url for this file, using cli tool I run next command `gsutil -m signurl -r <region> <path_to_the_service_account> gs://example_bucket/first_file.jpeg` which will return signed url, using this url I want to download this file, but response doesn't contains any filename information(I wanna get original "first_file.jpeg" filename).

Comment: Lem - edit your question to improve.